# Add a buffer to numbers that are too close together using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with several text columns and a values column. I want to add a buffer (+0.2 for example) to values that are within a certain threshold (1.0) to any other value in the dataframe.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1l6_S1M1LCsEWTIGZxt03NMGxL1bzzKlC?usp=sharing

I could do this an extremely manual way by sorting and iterating over the list of values and appending those back to the dataframe, but there must be a better way to do this using pandas?

```
for i, v in enumerate(values_list):
  if i > 0 and i < len(values_list) - 1:
    if (abs(v - values_list[i-1]) < THRESHOLD) or (abs(v - values_list[i+1]) < THRESHOLD):
      v += BUFFER
      new_list.append(v)
    else:
      new_list.append(v)      
  else:
    new_list.append(v)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you say you want to do.  You only compare each value with the values adjacent to it in the list, but you say you want to compare with "any other value" in the list.  Also, adding BUFFER is not guaranteed to result in a new list where the items are always separated from one another by more than THRESHOLD, since your comparison involves absolute values and you always add BUFFER.  For example, if v < values_list[i-1].then adding BUFFER to v could make v closer to values_list[i-1]  
instead of farther apart.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: No, you're right about the buffer. Basically, all I want is a way to separate out the values in the list to make sure they are not the same as any other point in the list. The reason for this is because they're being plotted using d3 and I'm trying to separate points that are at the same X, Y value so that the points are visible.

Comment: If you fudge the point values before plotting them, then you will not be graphing your actual data set.  If your graph consists of just X,Y points, why not just draw them?  If 2 points overlap, so be it - it won't hurt anything.  If you want to draw text labels at each point, then you have a design problem, namely, how do you make a legible graph when some of the labels overlap?  In that case you have a different problem than the one asked about.  I don't know what d3 is so I'm probably not able to help.

Comment: D3 is just a JavaScript visualization library for drawing custom graphics. Normally, I would not be concerned about the X, Y points overlapping as you mentioned because of the data integrity.. but in this case the X, Y coordinates are coordinates of assets being tracked and plotted on a vector map, so fudging the numbers is really just changing these by a few degrees so that they are visible. Having the data exact is not as important in this case as being able to see the assets on the vector map.